# Djangobb problem

Tags: python, django, mod-python

I've installed Djangobb app on my server (Debian, mod_python) by cloning original source. The only things I've changed is database options in settings.py. All needed components are installed - syncdb query was executed right.

But, when I'm trying to enter on my forum, it returns me error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django_authopenid.middleware: "No module named djangobb_forum.subscription"

I've checked - djangobb_forum/subscription.py exist, so I don't know what can be wrong.

Maybe someone had problems like that and know how to fix it?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

There are two obvious reasons to why this might happen:

1. `djangobb_forum` is not on your Python path
2. There is no `__init__.py` in the `djangobb_forum` folder

If the code says `from djangobb_forum import ...` then you need to have the parent folder of `djangobb_forum` on your Python path.

Comment: It works, but I have another problem: "Caught an exception while rendering: u'djangobb' is not a registered namespace" - in base template. How can I fix it?

Comment: maybe best place for this question at http://support.djangobb.org/
for namespace defiane it in urls.py